# How do I draw curve + straight line to show possible path once player click on any position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a turn based game where the actors are ships. As such, the movement set to change its location will require both Vector3.Forward and Vector3.Rotation.

I got the code for actually making it move working already and I'm able to generate/create path taken using both LineRenderer and Debug.DrawLine.

However, I can't seem to find any resource for drawing out the node/line to **show the player's path BEFORE it actually move**.

Below is sample of the codes that I'm emulating.

```
void Update () {
    if (this.isMoving){
        if(Vector3.Distance(walkDestination, transform.position) > 0.2f){
            float step = 0f;
            step = this.speed * Time.deltaTime;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, walkDestination, step);

            Vector3 rotationDestination = this.rotateDestination;
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(rotationDestination - transform.position, Vector3.up);
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, Time.deltaTime * 6.0f);
        }else{
            //Arrived to destination
        }
    }
}
```

Most if not all resources are pointing out to NavMesh or grid like system which doesn't align with my system as I'm allowing movement to be unrestricted on a quad.

I'd appreciate if anyone can point me to a right direction to draw POSSIBLE path from point A to point B before the unit actually moved.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for Unity's Line Renderer component:

- [Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-LineRenderer.html)
- [Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bqcu94VuVOI)
- [Forum Post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/drawing-simple-lines-and-curves.450516/)

hth.

Comment: Thanks but I'm able and have used both LineRenderer and Debug.DrawLine to draw line to denote taken path but only AFTER the object moved. Edited main thread.